# Flask update issue on JSON encoder

Tags: json, flask

I am using a Flask application with custom JSON encoder. I am dealing with custom objects, with a custom serialization function named "serializable"

On the 2.2.x (2.2.5 to be precise) version of Flask, I had the following:

```
from flask import abort, Flask, json, jsonify, render_template, request

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if hasattr(o, 'serializable'):
            return o.serializable()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

class RunnerApi:
    def __init__():
        self.app = Flask(
            appname,
            static_folder=os.path.join(root_dir, "dist"),
            template_folder=root_dir)
        self.app.json_encoder = MyEncoder
```

I would like to update to latest Flask version (2.3.x) but I need to keep using my custom encoder. I have written this:

```
import json as _json

class MyEncoder(JSONProvider):
    def dumps(self, obj: t.Any, **kwargs: t.Any) -> str:
        if hasattr(obj, 'serializable'):
            return obj.serializable()
        return _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)

    def loads(self, s: t.Union[str, bytes], **kwargs: t.Any) -> t.Any:
        return _json.loads(s, **kwargs)

class RunnerApi:
    def __init__():
        self.app = Flask(
            appname,
            static_folder=os.path.join(root_dir, "dist"),
            template_folder=root_dir)
        self.app.json = MyEncoder(self.app)
```

But it does not work, this does not call my custom "serializable" function and raises exceptions such as the type is not jsonifiable.
Anyone has the tip to get the this update working ?

Comment: Having the same issue here. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I actually solved this exact issue on my code. Hopefully works for you.
Referece: https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/608#issuecomment-636814475

Your CustomEncoder:

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

        if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            return obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        ...

        return super().default(obj)
```

CustomJsonProvider:

```
class CustomJSONProvider(JSONProvider):
    def dumps(self, obj, **kwargs):
        return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs, cls=MyEncoder)

    def loads(self, s: str or bytes, **kwargs):
        return json.loads(s, **kwargs)
```

Then:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.json = rvme.lib.output_utils.CustomJSONProvider(app)
app.config["RESTX_JSON"] = {'cls': rvme.lib.output_utils.MyEncoder}
```